# How to avoid useRef impacting other elements in the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-hooks

I was using this code as reference to build a swipeable list of names https://gist.github.com/estaub/91e54880d77a9d6574b829cb0d3ba021

That code becomes a JSX component. I then had a parent component holding two lists, and the idea is to make an item from one of the lists go to the second list when we swipe it.

The code works fine, the problem started when I implemented the lists. When I swipe an Item, the parent component triggers a function that gets the swiped Item, removes from the first and add to the second list. The parent component gets rendered again. **The problem is that the item below this one that was erased seems to be receiving the classes that was added to to make the item disappear. In other words, it's like if I was erasing two items. The erased item gets removed from the list, but the item below it still in the DOM now with the properties that hides it, so we can't see it anymore.**

For some reason it seems like useRef is selecting the element below the one that has just been erased and applying the styles to it.

Any idea what I could try to solve it?

**Here is my swipeable component**

```
import React, {
  useEffect, useRef,
} from 'react';

  interface IOwnProps {
      onSwipe?: () => void;
  }

const SwipeableListItem:React.FC<IOwnProps> = ({
  children, onSwipe,
}) => {
  const listElementRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
  const wrapperRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
  const backgroundRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);

  const dragStartXRef = useRef(0);
  const leftRef = useRef(0);
  const draggedRef = useRef(false);


  useEffect(() => {
    const onSwiped = () => {
      if (onSwipe) {
        onSwipe();
      }
    };

    const onDragEnd = () => {
      if (draggedRef.current) {
        draggedRef.current = false;
        const threshold = 0.3;

        let elementOffsetWidth = 0;
        if (listElementRef.current) {
          elementOffsetWidth = listElementRef.current.offsetWidth;
        }

        if (leftRef.current < elementOffsetWidth * threshold * -1) {
          leftRef.current = (-elementOffsetWidth * 2);

          if (wrapperRef.current) {
            wrapperRef.current.style.maxHeight = (0).toFixed(1);
          }
          onSwiped();
        } else {
          leftRef.current = 0;
        }

        if (listElementRef.current) {
          listElementRef.current.className = 'BouncingListItem';
          listElementRef.current.style.transform = `translateX(${leftRef.current}px)`;
        }
      }
    };


    const onDragEndMouse = (ev: MouseEvent) => {
      window.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
      onDragEnd();
    };

    const onDragEndTouch = (ev: TouchEvent) => {
      window.removeEventListener('touchmove', onTouchMove);
      onDragEnd();
    };


    window.addEventListener('mouseup', onDragEndMouse);
    window.addEventListener('touchend', onDragEndTouch);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('mouseup', onDragEndMouse);
      window.removeEventListener('touchend', onDragEndTouch);
    };
  }, [onSwipe]);


  const onDragStartMouse = (ev: React.MouseEvent) => {
    onDragStart(ev.clientX);
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
  };

  const onDragStartTouch = (ev: React.TouchEvent) => {
    const touch = ev.targetTouches[0];
    onDragStart(touch.clientX);
    window.addEventListener('touchmove', onTouchMove);
  };

  const onDragStart = (clientX: number) => {
    draggedRef.current = true;
    dragStartXRef.current = clientX;

    if (listElementRef.current) {
      listElementRef.current.className = 'ListItem';
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(updatePosition);
  };


  const updatePosition = () => {
    if (draggedRef.current) {
      requestAnimationFrame(updatePosition);
    }

    if (listElementRef.current) {
      listElementRef.current.style.transform = `translateX(${leftRef.current}px)`;
    }

    // fade effect
    const opacity = (Math.abs(leftRef.current) / 100);
    if (opacity < 1 && opacity.toString() !== backgroundRef.current?.style.opacity) {
      if (backgroundRef.current) {
        backgroundRef.current.style.opacity = opacity.toString();
      }
    }
  };

  const onMouseMove = (ev: MouseEvent) => {
    const left = ev.clientX - dragStartXRef.current;
    if (left < 0) {
      leftRef.current = left;
    }
  };

  const onTouchMove = (ev: TouchEvent) => {
    const touch = ev.targetTouches[0];
    const left = touch.clientX - dragStartXRef.current;
    if (left < 0) {
      leftRef.current = left;
    }
  };


  return (
    <div className="Wrapper" ref={wrapperRef}>
      <div className="Background" ref={backgroundRef}>
        <span>Remove</span>
      </div>
      <div
        className="ListItem"
        ref={listElementRef}
        onMouseDown={onDragStartMouse}
        onTouchStart={onDragStartTouch}
        role="presentation"
      >
        {children}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SwipeableListItem;
```

**Here is the parent component, where I handle the lists**

```
import React, {
  useEffect, useState,
} from 'react';
import SwipeableListItem from './SwipeableListItem';


interface ITest{
    id:number;
}

  interface IOwnProps{
      list1?: ITest[];
      list2?: ITest[];
  }

const MyList: React.FC<IOwnProps> = ({
  list1, list2,
}) => {
  const [displayList1, setDisplayList1] = useState<boolean>(true);

  const [list, setList] = useState<Array<Array<ITest>>>([[], []]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setList([list1 || [], list2 || []]);
  }, [list1, list2]);


  const handleSwitchList = () => {
    setDisplayList1(!displayList1);
  };

  //without this function it works, but the item does not get removed from the list
  const handleSendToSecondList = (id: number, myList1: ITest[], myList2: ITest[]) => {
    const foundItem = myList2.find((s) => s.id === id);
    const newList1 = myList1;

    if (foundItem) {
      // push item to list 1
      newList1.push(foundItem);

      // remove list 2
      const newList2 = myList2.filter((s) => s.id !== foundItem.id);

      setList([newList1, newList2]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>

      <div>
        <button
          type="button"
          className={`btn  ${displayList1 ? 'btn-primary' : ''}`}
          onClick={handleSwitchList}
        >
          List 1
        </button>
        <button
          type="button"
          className={`btn  ${!displayList1 ? 'btn-primary' : ''}`}
          onClick={handleSwitchList}
        >
          List 2
        </button>
      </div>
      {
          displayList1
            ? list[1]?.map((item) => (
              <SwipeableListItem onSwipe={() => handleSendToSecondList(item.id, list[0], list[1])}>
                <p>{item.id}</p>
              </SwipeableListItem>
            ))
            : list[0]?.map((item) => (
              <SwipeableListItem>
                <p>{item.id}</p>
              </SwipeableListItem>
            ))
        }
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyList;
```

I created this just to show what is happening
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-usestate-kbvqt?file=/src/index.js

The problem is happening here but a little different. There are two lists, if you swipe an item from the first list, an item from the second list will disappear, because it received the css properties.